# Is it possible to estimate the young's modulus of an aluminum alloy purely based off its alloy designation?

Tags: materials, metals, aluminum, material-science

I recently had an interview where the interviewer asked what the young's modulus would be like for an alloy like 5052 versus 6061.

was a bit stumped on this one, saying that 5052 might be lower considering that it's often used for bending (and I assumed a metal that's good for bending is probably easier to bend). Anyway, a quick Google search says that 5052 has a young's modulus of 69.3 GPa, and 6061's is 68 GPa (so I was wrong).

What would have been an appropiate answer to this?

I also thought that the trick to this was the alloy composition. 5XXX series aluminums are Al-Mg while 6XXX series aluminums contain Al-Mg-Si. However I remember being told during the interview that it wasn't the primary factor here.

Comment: The elastic modulus is generated by simple physical processes and can be approximated by a rule of mixtures (Voigt and Reuss bounds).  Since the volume fraction of alloying materials in Al-alloys is typically small (less than 5-10%), the elastic modulus is (to a good approximation) equal to that of pure Al (~70 GPa).

Comment: I see, okay. I guess that makes sense.  It was a strange question, I'm not entirely sure what they were looking for there other than a general intuition as to the elastic modulus of aluminum.

Answer (score 1):

the modulus of the most commonly used metallic alloys remains unaffected. So for example most steel alloys have a young's modulus of 200GPa to 210GPa. At least to my knowledge it is common practice to use a common value for modulus.

The strength is more markedly affected by composition of the alloy.

Comment: Cast iron is the only metal  for which modulus can vary significantly.

Comment: That's true. Cast iron has lower modulus from other steels and it's also very Inconsistent